Search for multiple words in a string and return all matched words in a concatenation way in Oracle SQL
I have a list of words:
Urgent, Disappointing, Pissed off, Unavailable, Escalate, Dissatisfied
MY table shows as below: Basically contains feedback.



SentenceID
Text




1
This is disappointing issue occurring again and again. Please fix this urgent


2
Dissatisfied with service. Escalate the case



I want to have something like below



SentenceID
Text
Words from List




1
This is disappointing issue occurring again and again. Please fix this urgent
Disappointing, Urgent


2
Dissatisfied with service. Escalate the case
Dissatisfied, Escalate




A simple option includes cross join between word list and sentences, usage of the instr function and aggregation of all matches per sentence.
Sample data:
SQL> with
  2  words (word) as
  3    (select 'Urgent'        from dual union all
  4     select 'Disappointing' from dual union all
  5     select 'Pissed off'    from dual union all
  6     select 'Unavailable'   from dual union all
  7     select 'Escalate'      from dual union all
  8     select 'Dissatisfied'  from dual
  9    ),
 10  sentences (id, text) as
 11    (select 1, 'This is disappointing issue occurring again and again. Please fix this urgent' from dual union all
 12     select 2, 'Dissatisfied with service. Escalate the case'                                  from dual
 13    )

Query begins here:
 14  select s.id, s.text,
 15    listagg(case when instr(upper(s.text), upper(w.word)) > 0 then w.word end, ', ')
 16      within group (order by w.word) as match
 17  from sentences s cross join words w
 18  group by s.id, s.text;

        ID TEXT                                     MATCH
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 This is disappointing issue occurring ag Disappointing, Urgent
           ain and again. Please fix this urgent

         2 Dissatisfied with service. Escalate the  Dissatisfied, Escalate
           case


SQL>

Note that this approach returns false positives if - for example - words contain "the", and sentence contains "Theodore". However, looking at what you posted, something like that might not be the case as words you're looking for are quite distinctive.

The above query works well, if the text field is of varchar or char data type. But fails once I use the query for clob datatype(field: text)

Indeed you can't group by CLOB, workaround is to group by a substr() or a hash of the CLOB. Also take a look at ORACLE text as alternative solution.
